# Virtual Environment Not Working . Typing venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 open notebook auto

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv

In Powershell  when i write venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 code .automatically open notepad file . Then how can I start virtual env?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this command to activate the virtual environment

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```